# How wordpress stores wp_usermeta?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm a php newbe and trying to learn from wordpress.
If I look to the  wp_usermeta starting-table it is defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE $wpdb->usermeta (
  umeta_id bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  user_id bigint(20) NOT NULL default '0',
  meta_key varchar(255) default NULL,
  meta_value longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY  (umeta_id),
  KEY user_id (user_id),
  KEY meta_key (meta_key)
) $charset_collate;";
```

If I look on a running wp-system there are columns added to this table like first_name or last_name.

To add this there must be a SQL-Statement like:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name datatype;
```

But I couln't find any statement like this in the wp-sources. Where is it declared? I'am espacially interested in the datatype. (Were is the pre-datatype stored?)

There seams to be a flexible system to add columns to the database. That I'am interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpess doesn't add the new columns to these database table. the fields like first name and last name are managed through the key-value pairs in this table rows. For example if there is a user with `id=1 and,` then an enrty is made in this table with

```
user_id=1, meta_key='first_name' and meta_value='John'
```

Comment: Oh: I see. Are there any standard meta_keys definded?

Comment: yes there are quite a few that Wp creates for the admin user that is created at the installation process. Few of them are `nickname`, 'first_name`, `last_name`, 'description`, `wp_capabalities` etc. You can see others here: http://prntscr.com/g5crfg